# WordPress internal URL routing / Rewrite API

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, routes

I have a WordPress theme with Custom Post Types. My URL Structure is /%category%/%postname% (this has to stay that way)

I also have a Custom Post Type "Cars" and a Category "Cars". When I enter domain.com/cars, WordPress will route to the archive.php template file (which is correct default behaviour).

What I want instead, is that URL pointing to the pretty URL of a page (which would have a custom template) that has the Permalink domain.com/cars (ugly URL would be domain.com/index.php?pagename=cars)

I tried this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrite_rules' );  
function add_rewrite_rules() {   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'cars/([^/]+)/?$',  
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',  
        'top');
}
```

I also flushed Rewrite Rules, but it does not work (nothing happens). Any Ideas?

Comment: WordPress automatically creates a permalink for your custom post type. So domain.com/%category%/%postname%/ doesn't work? Or are you trying to create a new permalink to show all and specific "cars"?

Comment: domain.com/%category%/%postname%/ works perfectly fine and domain.com/%customposttype%/postname works fine. Problem: I want to route domain.com/cars to a page instead the archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution (for functions.php):

The first line matches URLs like cars/mustang, the second one points /cars to the page named cars.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^cars/([^/]*)/?','cars/$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^cars$','index.php?pagename=cars','top');
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules in Settings->Permalinks